# Need to use no.nils.wsdl2java for gradle 7.0.2 and JDK 8.0.332.9

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle, wsdl2java

I need to use wsdl2 plugin for gradle 7.0.2 and my JDK version is 8.0.332.9

Below is the lines of code in build.gradle I wrote but I am getting an error Failed to apply plugin no.nils.wsdl2java > Configuration with name 'compile' not found.

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.7.0'
        sys_user = System.env.SYS_USER
        sys_pass = System.env.SYS_PASSWORD
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            // url
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.1.1')
        classpath('org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.21.0')
        classpath("org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:5.1.1")
        classpath("no.nils:wsdl2java:0.12")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'org.openapi.generator'
apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'
```